# Can't get plugin for Vim to work with Vundle. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: centos, vim

I am trying to install this plugin [here](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) for my Vim on my Centos 7 laptop. The instructions I followed to install the plugin manage Vundle are from the Github Vundle page [here](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) and then proceeded to follow instructions for the plugin installation in it's github page as well.

This is what my `.vimrc` file currently looks like which is practically taken from the Github Vundle page.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
" "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
"
" " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
"
" " The following are examples of different formats supported.
" " Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" " plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" " plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" " Plugin 'L9'
" " Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" " git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
"Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" " The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" " Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" " Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" " different version somewhere else.
" " Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
"
" " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line

"Adam - my plugins
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim' "download from - https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
" "filetype plugin on
" "
" " Brief help
" " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just
" :PluginUpdate
" " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to
" auto-approve removal
" "
" " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"show numbers on lines
"set number
".vimrc" 54L, 2126C                                                                                                                 52,1          90%
```

I save and close the file. Open vim again and run `:PluginInstall` and it seems to be installing as I get the result below shown in this

[image]

I then close vim and terminal, reopen everything but my status line still looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzgUv.png).

Comment: Looks like you missed setting `laststatus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New answer:

Maybe it is a configuration problem of the plugin, try adding `set laststatus=2` to your `.vimrc` - for details see: https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim#introduction

## Old answer:

it seems that you are missing `call vundle#begin()`:

Check example in the https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start

> Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.

Comment: i apologize, i did not notice i only pasted a section of my .vimrc file, I updated the code to show the entire file and it is in there.

Comment: The issue is with the status bar not looking as per plugin? It seems all is working but needs a bit of configuration - answer updated.

Comment: Solved. I was under the assumption that I did not need to put this in the line "set laststatus = 2" since my status line was not entirely blank like the document shows so did not bother to try it but it was the solution to my problem. Thank you.